# How to store Array for new field type extention in Bolt cms

Tags: arrays, bolt-cms, custom-field-type

I am working on an extension to replace the select field type with radio/check boxes in Bolt cms. My problem is how to use bolt internals to store selected values.

Ajax POST data when I press save:

```
day[]: Monday
day[]: Friday
```

So this is the same as for select fields.

I followed this tutorial: https://docs.bolt.cm/extensions/customfields
and used

```
public function getStorageType(){
    return 'text';
}
```

The response of the ajax-save request for this field is Array and this is what gets into the database. Interestingly select fields does not appear in this response. I can not find the place where data of select-fields are stored in app-code.

How can I store it correctly into database?
Using getStorageType 'json-array' results in wrong database scheme which bolt is not able to solve.

You can have a look on the code here:
https://github.com/osfriese/bolt-boxselect/tree/develope

Please help. Thanks
Tobi

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - more or less.

Sadly it is hardcoded in src/Content.php.
If you want a custom fieltype wich stores array values you have to change the select case in function **getValues** to:

```
                    default:
                        if (is_array($this->values[$field])) {
                            $newvalue[$field] = json_encode($this->values[$field]);
                        }else{
                            $newvalue[$field] = $this->values[$field];
                        }
                        break;
```

And in **setValues** there is a *$serializedFieldTypes = array(...)* where you have to manual add your custom field type.

Sadly this is not practical for extentions. But I will update my github with my changed Content.php for people who want to have a look.

When I was searching for an solution I reviewed a lot of source code of bolt master branch at github. For version 2.3 the storage layer is completely rebuild and as it seems there will be no need for any changes than. So hopefully with version >=2.3 the extention will work out of the box.

Nevertheless **getStorageType()** just just affect database field type and bolt just accepts 'text' here.

Hope I can help some people by answering my own question.

Thanks
Tobi